# FadeInLeft effect when changing content

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scrollDistance = window.scrollY;

    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.section1').forEach((el, i) => {
            if (el.offsetTop - document.querySelector('.nav').clientHeight <= scrollDistance) {
                document.querySelectorAll('.nav a').forEach((el) => {
                    if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
                        el.classList.remove('active');
                    }
                });

                document.querySelectorAll('.nav li')[i].querySelector('a').classList.add('active');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  padding: 100px;
}

.block-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.section-left {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  /* background: gray; */
  width: 100%;
}

.section-right {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: red;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /*     padding: 20px;
*/
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  display: flex !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black !important;
  display: inline-block;
  /*     margin-right: 25px !important;
 */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

.subtitle {

  opacity: 0;

}



.active {

  opacity: 1;

}

.content1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="section-left">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="" class="active subtitle">
              <div class="content1">
                <h1>O1</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>

          <li><a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content2">
                <h1>O2</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>

          <li><a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content3">
                <h1>O3</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>

          <li><a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content4">
                <h1>O4</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="section-right">
      <div class="section1 wrap">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1 ">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

How can I get the FadeInLeft effect when changing content from `.opacity=0` to `.opacity=1` on the left side.
I tried to solve this problem with the given script, but it did not work for me.
P.S. See this layout in fullscreen.

Comment: I doubt you need the JS.... Have a go at it using `animate.css`. For installation, scroll down to the bit which says `Or add it directly to your webpage using a CDN:`.......
https://animate.style/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if you haven't tried to apply your solution in this example code, your answer may be considered useless. I can get this effect in any other part of the code of this page and for this I do not need a third-party library

Comment: If I add .FadeInLeft to <a class='subtitle ...'> using this script, then the effect works strangely when scrolling the page. Are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Here is a very ruff first draft

Since you already have the `.active` class being added to your `.subtitle` class to change opacity, you can just tack on CSS Animation to those classes.

In my example I have `.subtitle > div` set to `right: 100%;` and `.active > div` set to `right: 0%;` with a `transition: 300ms;`

Which will animate the block from the left side of the screen over to the right side in 300ms.  You can play around with this until you get the animation where you'd like.

Here's a great article from MDN with more information about [Using CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

> CSS transitions provide a way to control animation speed when changing CSS properties. Instead of having property changes take effect immediately, you can cause the changes in a property to take place over a period of time. For example, if you change the color of an element from white to black, usually the change is instantaneous. With CSS transitions enabled, changes occur at time intervals that follow an acceleration curve, all of which can be customized.

#### Examples

```
div {
    transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
}
```

---

```
#delay {
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-property: font-size;
  transition-duration: 4s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

#delay:hover {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

---

```
.box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scrollDistance = window.scrollY;

    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.section1').forEach((el, i) => {
            if (el.offsetTop - document.querySelector('.nav').clientHeight <= scrollDistance) {
                document.querySelectorAll('.nav a').forEach((el) => {
                    if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
                        el.classList.remove('active');
                    }
                });

                document.querySelectorAll('.nav li')[i].querySelector('a').classList.add('active');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  padding: 100px;
}

.block-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.section-left {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  /* background: gray; */
  width: 100%;
}

.section-right {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: red;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /*     padding: 20px;
*/
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  display: flex !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black !important;
  display: inline-block;
  /*     margin-right: 25px !important;
 */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

.subtitle {
  opacity: 0;
  transition:300ms;
}


.subtitle > div {
  transition:300ms;
  right:100%;
}

.subtitle > div h1 {
  opacity:0;
  position:relative;
  top:2em;
  transition:300ms;
  transition-delay:1s;
}


.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.active > div {
  right:0;
}

.active > div h1 {
  opacity:1;
  top: 0;
}

.content1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="section-left">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="" class="active subtitle">
              <div class="content1">
                <h1>O1</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>

          <li><a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content2">
                <h1>O2</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>

          <li><a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content3">
                <h1>O3</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>

          <li><a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content4">
                <h1>O4</h1>
              </div>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="section-right">
      <div class="section1 wrap">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1 ">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. You solved this problem very simply and this solution works well for me

Comment: One more question. I would like to make a separate 1s delay animation for .subtitle h1 following the same rule. Can you help?

Comment: There is support for [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay).  I've updated the snippet to have the H1's opacity change from 0 to 1 after 1s.

Comment: I tried to do the same. But unfortunately this only works with opacity = 1, but not with top = 0 for .active, to get the FadeInUp effect for subtitle h1.

Comment: Just updated the snippet again to show the fadeInUp effect.   You can not position a static element, so you have to manually declare the H1 to be `position: relative;` (Or any other position that's not static.

Comment: [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document. The top, right, bottom, left, and z-index properties have no effect. This is the default value.

Comment: Cool. With your help, I got what I wanted. Thanks a lot and good luck